# TypeError: mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype' # Pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to get the `numpy.mean` of each column of my `pandas.DataFrame`.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

prices = pd.DataFrame([[-0.33333333, -0.25343423, -0.1666666667],
                       [+0.23432323, +0.14285714, -0.0769230769],
                       [+0.42857143, +0.07692308, +0.1818181818]])

print(np.mean(prices, axis=0))
```

If I run this code, I'll get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\Documents\Python\******\****.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(np.mean(new, axis=0))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2711, in mean
    return mean(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out)
TypeError: mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

How can I fix that?

**NOTE:** here is an expected output: `pd.DataFrame([0.1098537767, -0.0112180033, -0.0205905206])`

Comment: FYI this is a numpy 1.8 'error'; pandas 0.13 will allow this to work (releasing shortly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html

```
>>> prices.mean(axis=0)
0    0.109854
1   -0.011218
2   -0.020591
dtype: float64
>>> type(prices.mean(axis=0))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

If you wanted a DataFrame instead of a Series:

```
price_means = pd.DataFrame(prices.mean(axis=0))
```